# Hue - Oozie Job failing - Unable to resolve parameters

Tags: oozie, hue

I am using Hue to run my workflow which uses parameters. I would like the workflow to pickup parameter from job.properties file without prompting the user. I intend to generate/modify this job.properties before every run with new parameter values.

My current setup, I have manually created job.properties file in the same working directory as workflow.xml. I have not added parameters to the hive action since this results in prompt. But the Hive SQL uses the same parameter as specified in the job.properties file.

When I run the Workflow it fails for being unable to resolve the parameters. I believe it is not picking up my job.properties file for some reason.

Any pointers will realy help? Beating my head for almost 2 days now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Workflow Editor?  At this time (Hue 3.7) job.properties is only picked up when [submitting a workflow from File Browser](http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-submit-any-oozie-jobs-directly-from/).

Properties need to be entered as 'Oozie parameters' in the Properties section of the workflow. Would just doing this solve your problem?